# Application crashing when moving from activity to another

Tags: android

First Activity :
It crashes when the button at the first activity gets  clicked

package com.example.android_hw_3;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button btn; 
    TextView tv; 
    Button btn2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
         tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 

         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                show();

            }
        });

         btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                move();

            }
        });
    }



    public void show()

    {
        tv.setText("This is a test ..Please work :$");


    }
    public void move()
    {

        Intent i = new Intent (this,Second.class);
        i.putExtra("value", "this is from first :D ");
        startActivityForResult(i,1);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Second :

```
package com.example.android_hw_3;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class Second extends Activity {
    TextView tv2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.second);
            Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
            String val1 = extra.getString("value");
            TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            tv2.setText(val1);
    }
```

Comment: could you post your logcat stack trace ? We want to see the error

Comment: Did you add the secondActivity in your androidmanifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `startActivityForResult` in your `move()` method. According to your situation you should use `startActivity(intent)` like: 
`Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this,Second.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", "this is from first :D ");`
        `startActivity(i);` 
 Also check in your Manifest that you should add the following line of code under application tag 
`<activity
            android:name="yourpackagename.Second">
        </activity>`
Hope this will help you 
 Also you should take a look at difference between `startActivity()` and `startActivityForResult()` [here](http://malikshafique.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/android-startactivity-and-startactivityforresult/) and [here](http://saiful103a.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/android-startactivity-and-startactivityforresult/)

Answer (score 1):

In Second Activity you are initializing TextView before setting layout for Activity so move it after `setContentView` as:

```
TextView tv2; //<< declare TextView here
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
         tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);  // initialize here
          // your code here...
     }
```

Comment: I moved the initializing statement down but it's still crashing

Comment: @HSN : make sure you have added Second Activity in android manifest and if still crashing then please add logcat result with question to get more help

Answer (score 1):

Fix your second activity class like this.

```
public class Second extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        String val1 = extra.getString("value");
        TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv2.setText(val1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did but it's still crashing